# Change table spacing

Tags: tables, spacing

I would like to create a table that looks like the one from Excel (First picture). But the top row is creating weird spacing in LaTeX (Second picture.) [image: Excel table]

```
    \usepackage{amsmath}                                                            
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm,
            inner=3cm, outer=2cm, footskip = 1.5cm]{geometry}       
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
    Study \\ month\end{tabular} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\ \hline

    SD & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Standard diet, \\fed 2\% of mean BW until 35kg, then fixed ration of 500g \end{tabular}}\\ \hline

    FFC & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}High fat, fructose, cholesterol (2\%), \\ fed 2\% of mean BW \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}High fat, fructose, cholesterol (1\%),\\ fed 2\% of mean BW (max 1000g) \end{tabular}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}High fat,fructose, \\cholesterol (1\%),\\
    changed to fixed\\ ration of 500g \end{tabular}} \\ \hline

    FFC/SD                                                 & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}High fat, fructose, cholesterol (2\%),\\ fed 2\% of mean BW
    \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}High fat, fructose,\\ cholesterol (1\%),\\ fed 2\% of mean \\ BW (max 1000g)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Changed to standard diet,  \\
    fed fixed ration of 500g.
    \end{tabular}}                                                              \\ \hline

    FFC$_{DIA}$                                                 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}High fat, fructose, cholesterol (1\%), \\
    fed 2.5\% of mean BW (max 1000g)
\end{tabular}}                                                                         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latex Table]

I feel I have tried everything, but I cannot fix it my self. 
Kindly asking for help.

Comment: This somes from the rules of `booktabs`, which are not designed for use with vertical rules as they add some vertical padding.  You can add, just after `\begin{table}`, `\aboverulesep=0pt` and `\belowrulesep=0pt`.

Comment: And the unequal space for your columns is caused by the way a too wide `\multicolumn` is handled (adding all of the excess space to the last column).

Comment: Don't use `\resizebox` and the like on tables. It causes inconsistent font sizes and spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following calculates the available width for equal spaced columns so that the resulting `tabular` is exactly `\linewidth` wide. The macro doing so is called `\equalspacing` and takes as arguments an optional first column (specify the widest entry) and the number of columns you need. The resulting column width is stored in `\equalspacingwidth`. The calculation assumes that there is a vertical rule everywhere and each column has a full `\tabcolsep` on both sides (so that you don't use `@{}`). You can then specify the columns with the `*{<count>}{<definition>}` notation (e.g. `*{13}{p{\equalspacingwidth}|}` in for 13 columns).

Further a `\multiequal{<count>}{<content>}` is defined, which is a `\multicolumn` as wide as `<count>` columns of width `\equalspacingwidth` (plus the `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth` for each of the spanned columns).

With these two macros you can get the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}                                                            
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm,
            inner=3cm, outer=2cm, footskip = 1.5cm]{geometry}       
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newlength\equalspacingwidth
\newsavebox\equalspacing@TMPbox
\newlength\equalspacing@tmp@length
\newcommand\equalspacing[2][]
  {%
    \equalspacingwidth\linewidth
    \equalspacing@tmp@length\arrayrulewidth
    \advance\equalspacing@tmp@length2\tabcolsep
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else
      \setbox\equalspacing@TMPbox\hbox
        {%
          \begingroup
          \def\colsep{\hskip2\tabcolsep}%
          \def\colsepR{\hskip2\tabcolsep\hskip\arrayrulewidth}%
          #1%
          \endgroup
        }%
      \advance\equalspacingwidth by -\wd\equalspacing@TMPbox
      \advance\equalspacingwidth by -2\tabcolsep
      \advance\equalspacingwidth by -\arrayrulewidth
    \fi
    \advance\equalspacingwidth by -\arrayrulewidth
    \divide\equalspacingwidth by #2
    \advance\equalspacingwidth by -\equalspacing@tmp@length
  }
\newcommand\multiequal[2]
  {%
    \multicolumn{#1}
      {%
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{%
          \dimexpr
            #1\equalspacingwidth
            +#1\arrayrulewidth
            +#1\tabcolsep
            +#1\tabcolsep
            -2\tabcolsep
            -\arrayrulewidth
          \relax
        }|%
      }{#2}%
  }
\newcommand\onecell[2][c]
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\equalspacing[FFC/SD]{13}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{13}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\equalspacingwidth}|}}
\hline
  \onecell{Study\\month}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\ \hline
  SD
    & \multiequal{13}
        {%
          Standard diet, fed 2\% of mean BW until 35kg, then fixed ration of
          500g%
        }
  \\ \hline
  FFC
    & \multiequal{5}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (2\%), fed 2\% of mean BW}
    & \multiequal{6}
        {High fat, fructose, cholesterol (1\%), fed 2\% of mean BW (max 1000g)}
    & \multiequal{2}
        {High fat,fructose, cholesterol (1\%), changed to fixed ration of 500g}
  \\ \hline
  FFC/SD
    & \multiequal{5}
        {High fat, fructose, cholesterol (2\%), fed 2\% of mean BW}
    & \multiequal{2}
        {High fat, fructose, cholesterol (1\%), fed 2\% of mean BW (max 1000g)}
    & \multiequal{6}{Changed to standard diet, fed fixed ration of 500g.}
  \\ \hline
  FFC$_{DIA}$
    & \multiequal{13}
        {%
          High fat, fructose, cholesterol (1\%), fed 2.5\% of mean BW (max
          1000g)%
        }
  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To get vertically centred cells, you can use the `m` specifier instead of `p` in the definition of `\multiequal`.

So with the following definition of `\multiequal` and the same remaining document you get this:

```
\newcommand\multiequal[2]
  {%
    \multicolumn{#1}
      {%
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{%
          \dimexpr
            #1\equalspacingwidth
            +#1\arrayrulewidth
            +#1\tabcolsep
            +#1\tabcolsep
            -2\tabcolsep
            -\arrayrulewidth
          \relax
        }|%
      }{#2}%
  }
```

[image]

Comment: @CamillaAarupKristensen glad it helped you. A thank you however should be expressed in votes rather than comments (if you didn't vote, that is). Furthermore you should accept the best suited answer (you got 3 to choose from and it's been 2 days).

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use the `array` package. Here's my proposed code. Notice I use `\tabularnewline` so as to avoid confusion with the `\\` in each paragraph cell. Also, you repeat `\multicolumn` a sufficient number of times that it justifies the creation of a `\cmulticolumn` command (which also includes some formatting parameters). The solution makes use of a nice thing about the `array` package: it allows one to define a tabular token (`z`, for example) which displays a paragraph of a given with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{z}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\newdimen\mycol
\setlength\mycol{10ex}
\def\cmulticolumn#1#2{%
\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{\parbox{#1\mycol}{\mbox{}\\[1ex]\centering#2\\\mbox{}}}
}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{|z{13ex}*{13}{|z{\mycol}}|}
\hline
Study month & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \tabularnewline\hline
SD & \cmulticolumn{13}{Standard diet,\\ fed 2\% of mean BW until 35kg, then fixed ration of 500g} \tabularnewline\hline
FFC & \cmulticolumn{5}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (2\%), \\ fed 2\% of mean BW} & \cmulticolumn{6}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (1\%),\\ fed 2\% of mean BW (max 1000g)} & \cmulticolumn{2}{High fat, fructose, \\ cholesterol (1\%),\\ changed to fixed\\ ration of 500g} \tabularnewline\hline
FFC/SD & \cmulticolumn{5}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (2\%),\\ fed 2\% of mean BW} & \cmulticolumn{2}{High fat, fructose,\\ cholesterol (1\%),\\ fed 2\% of mean \\ BW (max 1000g)} & \cmulticolumn{6}{Changed to standard diet, \\ fed fixed ration of 500g.}\tabularnewline \hline
FFC$_{DIA}$ & \cmulticolumn{13}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (1\%), \\ fed 2.5\% of mean BW (max 1000g)} \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `\newcolumntype{z}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` for the column definition. This way you don't need to use `\tabularnewline` after a column using this definition.

Comment: Good point, @Slillmon; thanks. I might add that my `\cmulticolumn` command does not make use of all of the space available since it does not include the space between columns. However, to the extent that the text is centered, this does not matter that much. Also, there may be more elegant ways of adding space above and below each row.

Answer (score 3):

**edit:**

- with use of the `tabularx`,
- text is vertically centered in cells by:

  ```
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  ```
- font size is set to `\footnotesize`
- for units in cells' contents is used the `siunitx` package
- more vertical space around  the cell contents is done by use of the `cellspace` package
- for preserving features of the `X` columns is used (modified) macro

  ```
  \addparagraphcolumntypes{>{\null}Y}
  ```

  where `Y` is defined by `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`
- width of the `multicolumn` cells is defined by new command

  ```
  \usepackage{xparse}
  \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\xmc{m m}%
      {\multicolumn{#1}
                   {C{>{\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+
                               #1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep+
                               #1\arrayrulewidth\relax}Y}|}
                   {#2}}
  ```
- mwe:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

  \usepackage{cellspace, makecell, tabularx}
  \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
  \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \addparagraphcolumntypes{>{\null}Y}
  \usepackage{xparse}
  \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\xmc{m m}%
      {\multicolumn{#1}
                   {C{>{\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+
                               #1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep+
                               #1\arrayrulewidth\relax}Y}|}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{table}
  \footnotesize
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Cc|*{13}{C{Y}|}}
      \hline
  \makecell{Study\\ month}
      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
      \hline
  SD  &   \multicolumn{13}{Cc|}{Standard diet,
          fed \SI{2}{\%} of mean BW until \SI{35}{kg}, then fixed ration of \SI{500}{g}} \\
      \hline
  FFC & \xmc{5}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (\SI{2}{\%}), fed \SI{2}{\%} of mean BW}
          &   \xmc{6}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (\SI{1}{\%}),
              fed \SI{2}{\%} of mean BW (max \SI{1000}{g})}
              &   \xmc{2}{High fat, fructose,  cholesterol (\SI{1}{\%}),
                  changed to fixed ration of \SI{500}{g}} \\
      \hline
  FFC/SD
      &   \xmc{5}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (\SI{2}{\%}),
          fed \SI{2}{\%} of mean BW}
              &   \xmc{2}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (\SI{1}{\%}),
                  fed \SI{2}{\%} of mean BW (max \SI{1000}{g})}
                  &   \xmc{6}{Changed to standard diet,
                      fed fixed ration of \SI{500}{g}.}\\
      \hline
  FFC$_\mathrm{DIA}$
      &   \multicolumn{13}{Cc|}{High fat, fructose, cholesterol (\si{1}{\%}),
          fed \SI{2.5}{\%} of mean BW (max \SI{1000}{g})} \\
      \hline
  \end{tabularx}
      \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Might be me, but from your screenshot the vertical rules don't seem aligned.

Comment: @Skillmon, your observation is very good :-)except for `mcx` i didn't consider `\arrayrulewidth` at other `\multicolum` cells. and also conside wrong numberof `\tabcolsep`. corrected now

Comment: You could create one `\mcx` for spanning arbitrary number of `X` columns (would be very similar to my `\multiequal`).

Comment: @Skillmon, done. i use `xparse` package for this and spend a wile to solve problem with `\addparagraphcolumntypes` which works properly at adjusting width of the  multicolumn` cells. see edited answer.